# Python Using Socket File Transfer

Tags: python

i have a small program for receiving a txt file from an arduino. the problem is sometimes it prints an empty file. i assume because the receiving part of the code is empty at the time. can someone help me make this code not write to the file when "t" is empty so i can prevent it from writing a blank txt file? thanks

```
with open('sensData.txt','wb') as f:
while True:
 t = conn.recv(20)
 print t
 if not t:
    s.close()
    break
 f.write(t) #Write To File UNLESS BLANK
```

Comment: How would you distinguish between end-of-file and simply a transfer “hiccup” then? You’d probably have to introduce a simple timeout to do that.

Comment: thats a good point. i dont know what to do at this point. ive only been learing python for 4 days now. what could i do to prevent a write on a corrupted transfer or a blank txt file, which is probably what is happening in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to try this :

```
  with open('sensData.txt','wb') as f:
    while True:
     t = conn.recv(1)
     print t
     if t =='':
        s.close()
        break
     f.write(t)
```

or you can populate a string and write it at once at the end of the loop

```
  with open('sensData.txt','wb') as f:
   receivedData = ""
    while True:
     t = conn.recv(1)
     print t
     if t =='':
        s.close()
        break
     receivedData+=t

   f.write(receivedData)
```

Comment: thankyou soo much, this answer my first question. another big problem i have is, i run this program in a batch script loop on windows for the time being which works except sometimes it freezes at calling the script. which probably is a messed up connection/transfer. what can i implement to prevent the scipt freezing at a corrupted connection?

Comment: I think with these changes you will not face this issue can you please try and share your experience?

Comment: yes thankyou im using it now. sometimes i wont have a problem for hours. now time will tell

Comment: accept the answer if you think the problem is solved

Comment: its still writing a blank file, altho t does = the received data? the problem is i cant let it print anything to the file if its blank ever

Comment: it will only work is i use "if not t:" if i use "if t =='':" it prints nothing to the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
if t != "":
    f.write(t)
```

if `t` is empty, this should work